# Red5 - Linux Installation init.d script

Tags: ubuntu, installation, red5

I have followed this pretty little [tutorial](http://tumbledesign.com/how-to-install-red5-0-9-on-ubuntu-10-04-lts/) to install red5 on Ubuntu 11.04
I can now run it from `/usr/share/red5/red5.sh`
But I'd like to have a init.d script like `/etc/init.d/red5 start|stop|restart|...`
I found one [here](http://www.linuxmaza.com/system-administration/init-script-to-start-stop-restart-red5-flash-media-server/) but when used, it's saying

> .: 11: Can't open /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

What can I do to make it work ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Startup script for Red5 on Ubuntu 9.04](http://serverfault.com/questions/166099/startup-script-for-red5-on-ubuntu-9-04)

Comment: You're using init script for the Red Hat based distro.

Comment: Ok I think you are right. Now I have another problem but I'll probably do an other question for that. Can you please put your comment as an answer so I can validate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` contains some functions: `daemon`, `killproc`, `status`, ... which is used in init script **on Red Hat based distro**. Since you're using Ubuntu, you probably want to 'convert':

- `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` >> `/lib/lsb/init-functions`
- `daemon` >> `start-stop-daemon`
- ...